# HTML fitting divs in divs

Tags: css, html

I am very simply trying to have 5 Divs inline, inside a div. I am doing this by simply creating a div, and inside that div having 5 divs with the widths of 20% each, all using inline-block.

However, all im getting is 4 of my divs in the parent div and the 5th overflowing onto the next line.

How could this be happening?   5 x 20 = 100%, so why does it seem to equal more?

[image]

[image]

http://pastebin.com/uS6vcwTM HTML code

http://pastebin.com/VKHS7swJ CSS code

Comment: Post your HTML and CSS please.

Comment: Oops typo in the question. Corrected. Will get onto a pastebin of HTML and CSS.

Comment: Do you have padding or margins on these elements?

Comment: Post your HTML and CSS. Here. Please.

Comment: Screenshot added showing what i see as no padding or margin shown within inspecting element

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inline elements are sensitive to white space. You can remove the white space between the divs like:

```
<div id="Navigation">
    <div class="NavButton">Button</div><div class="NavButton">Button</div><div class="NavButton">Button</div><div class="NavButton">Button</div><div class="NavButton">Button</div>
</div>
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/MvzS3/2/)**

Or add `float:left` to the `NavButton` class.

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/MvzS3/4/)**

Comment: Using float:left has worked beautifully for me. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

`Inline-block` takes account of whitespace in your HTML.

This usually equates to .0.25em or 4px depending on your browsers basic font-size.

There are a couple of techniques to solve this.

The first and perhaps simplest involves setting  the font size of the parent to 0. The font size would then need to be reset in the children...the boxes

**[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/XbwhC/)**

Comment: of just float the inner divs

Comment: @Paul, I have tried setting parents font size to 0 and the whole thing goes crazy. However I feel you are correct..